# How to use a common find text box for all tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Recent versions of Firefox have introduced a separate find box for each tab.

Is there any config variable in about:config or any addon to disable tab level search in Firefox or use a common find text box for all tabs?

Comment: we can use Find Bar TweaK https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/findbar-tweak/?src=ss addon for global search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GlobalFindBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/globalfindbar/):

> Since Firefox 25, the FindBar was made independent for each tab. This addon reverts the FindBar to classic/global behavior.